# Content Hashes, ExtractTextPlugin and HtmlWebpackPlugin

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, frontend, webpack-2

I guess I'll start with my webpack config.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

/**
 * Environment
 */
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isProduction = nodeEnv === 'production';
const isDevelopment = !isProduction;

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, 'assets');
const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
  disable: isDevelopment
});

/**
 * Plugins
 */
const plugins = [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(sourcePath, 'index.html'),
  }),
  extractSass
];

if (isProduction) {
} else {
  plugins.concat([
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ]);
}

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./assets/app.js', './assets/app.scss'],
  devtool: isProduction ? 'eval' : 'source-map',
  plugins: plugins,
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: extractSass.extract({
        use: [{
          loader: "css-loader"
        }, {
          loader: "sass-loader"
        }],
        // use style-loader in development
        fallback: "style-loader"
      })
    }]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: buildPath
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: buildPath,
    port: 9000
  }
};
```

This all works fine when running on the webpack dev server but I'm trying to figure out how this fits together on a production environment.

As you can see, as per the sass-loader documentation, I'm creating a file called `[name].[contenthash].css` if `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`. I love the idea of serving files based on the content hash because I love integrity.

The difficulty I'm having is understanding how I can pass that file name, that content hash into the index.html template I'm creating so that I can `<link>` the stylesheet.

- Is it a server side thing?
- Is there any way to pass that file name into the HTML template on
  production?
- Is it intentional that I do it manually or script it out?

I just don't understand how these two components come together to produce a publishable build. `HtmlWebpackPlugin` produced a .html in the output directory but obviously it has no innate understanding of where to find it's styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config seems correct.

> Is there any way to pass that file name into the HTML template on production?

What should be happening is that the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` should be creating a new `index.html` file in your `buildPath` directory, which has the generated bundles automatically injected in it (for example the generated CSS bundle will be injected in the `head` tag and the generated script bundles at the bottom of the `body` tag)

Beyond that it is just a matter of serving that `dist/index.html` to whoever visits your site/app. So the answer to

> Is it a server side thing?

is yes.

Try doing a build without the dev server, by simply running `webpack`, so you can see the output of your configuration (the dev server builds things in memory, so you do not actually get to see them)

Comment: I'll have to get back to you on this. Sorry for the wait.